# $s_1(A) ≥ s_2(A) ≥ · · · ≥ s_n(A) ≥ 0$ are singular value of $A$, why does $|s_n(A + B) − s_n(A)| ≤ s_1(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any matrix $A ∈ \mathbb{C}^{n×n}$, we denote by $s_1(A) ≥ s_2(A) ≥ · · · ≥ s_n(A) ≥ 0$ the singular values of $A$.

Now, let $A,B ∈ \mathbb{C}^{n×n}$.

Why does $|s_n(A + B) − s_n(A)| ≤ s_1(B)$?

Comment: have you tried  Courant-Fischer-Weyl theorem?

Comment: http://www.math.uh.edu/~bgb/Courses/Math6304/MatrixTheory-20121011.pdf

Comment: @  Razieh Noor - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it suffices to prove that
$$
s_n(A+B) \leq s_n(A) + s_1(B)
$$
This is simply an application of [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) (see the comment for a proof).

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom- In Weyl's inequality, $A,B$ are Hermitian.Is this not necessary for this question?

Comment: Note that the singular values of $M$ are the eigenvalues of $M^*M$, which is Hermitian and positive definite.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom - Thanks